# NoReverseMatch at /users/login/

Tags: python, django

'learning.logs' is not a registered namespace.
Request Method:
GET
Request URL:
http://localhost:8000/users/login/
Django Version:
2.2.7
Exception Type:
NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:
'learning.logs' is not a registered namespace

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
# my_apps
'learning_logs',
'users',
]
```

**learning_log\urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/',include('users.urls', namespace='users')),
    path('',include('learning_logs.urls', namespace='learning_logs')),
]
```

**users\urls.py**

```
from django.urls import re_path, path, include
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from . import views

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    # log in page
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'),name='login'),

]
```

**learning_logs\urls.py**

```
from django.urls import re_path
from . import views

app_name = 'learning_logs'

urlpatterns = [
# homepage
re_path('^$', views.index, name='index'),

# show all topics
re_path('^topics/$', views.topics, name='topics'),

# show dedicated topic
re_path('^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views.topic, name='topic'),

# added new topic
re_path('^new_topic/$', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),

# added new entry
re_path('^new_entry/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views.new_entry, name='new_entry'),

# edit entry
re_path('^edit_entry/(?P<entry_id>\d+)/$', views.edit_entry, name='edit_entry'),
]
```

**login.html**

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  {% if form.errors %}
  <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
  {% endif %}

  <form method="post" action="{% url 'users:login' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}

  <button name="submit">log in</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'learning.logs:index' %}" />
  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

**base.html**

```
<p>
  <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">Learning Log</a> -
  <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topics' %}">Topics</a> -
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    Hello, {{ user.username }}.
  {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'users:login' %}">log in</a>
  {% endif %}
</p>

{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You've included a lot of code and an error message, could you please add a description of the issue, what you want to solve

Comment: I'm setting up a website, and want to make a user login page. But I always get "NoReverseMatch at /users/login/ and 'learning.logs' is not a registered namespace" when I am on the login page.

Answer (score 0):

In your template **login.html** you reference the url by the name learning.logs:index but the namespace you have created is learning_logs.

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'learning.logs:index' %}" />
```

Just fix the typo in the template and you should be fine.